# Impedir la importación de datos existentes de Excel a Access

Tags: vba, ms-access, vb, importación

Tengo una tabla Excel llamada "*resultado*", la cual tiene 100 datos. Aunque de estos 100 datos, se irán añadiendo más al cabo del tiempo. 
Cada dato puede tener una id duplicada, es decir, puede haber 2 ids "1", o 5 ids "15".

Al importar estos datos a Access, funciona perfectamente. El problema está cuando se añaden más datos en la tabla de excel, ya que con el código actual que tengo, se importan los datos ya existentes en Access más los nuevos datos.

Este es mi código:

```
Private Sub ImportarDatosDeExcel_Click()

Call fimportAllFiles

End Sub

Function fimportAllFiles()

Dim strPathFile As String, strFile As String, strPath As String

Dim strTable As String

Dim blnHasFieldNames As Boolean

blnHasFieldNames = True

strPath = "C:\x\"

strTable = "dbo_Control_Tareas"

strFile = Dir(strPath + "*.xls")

Do While Len(strFile) > 0

strPathFile = strPath & strFile

DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel8, strTable, strPathFile, blnHasFieldNames

strFile = Dir()

Loop

MsgBox "Listo"

End Function
```

¿Cómo podría actualizar la base de datos únicamente con los nuevos datos que se añadan al excel?

He estado buscando y no logro encontrar nada relacionado. Por si acaso no me expliqué bien, pongo un ejemplo:

Tengo una tabla en excel con las ids:

> 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5

Al exportarlo esos datos a Access sale satisfactoriamente. Pero entonces, añado más datos en excel.

Ahora la tabla estaría así:

> 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6

Y al pasar los datos en Access, efectivamente se importan pero ahora la base de datos queda así:

> 1,1,2,3,4,4,5, 1,1,2,2,3,4,4,5,5,6

Cuando tiene que quedar igual que como está en el Excel, añadir los que no están.

Comment: Limpia la hoja de cálculo con los datos que ya existan. Deberías tener un campo que identifique a cada fila de manera única, precisamente para estos casos. Luego, antes de importar estos datos a Access, que tu macro compruebe si esas filas ya existían o no. Borra en el Excel lo que ya exista, y luego ya haces el transfer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conseguí lo que quería con el siguiente código:

```
Private Sub ImportarExcel_Click()

Dim rutaExcel As String

    rutaExcel = "\ruta\excel.xlsx"

    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, , "tabla", rutaExcel, True

    CurrentDb.Execute ("INSERT INTO tablaSQL SELECT * FROM tabla")

    DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, "tabla"

    MsgBox "Importación de datos realizada correctamente", vbInformation, "CORRECTO"

End Sub
```